# Inserir array no banco com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

Tenho um formulário que retorna um array com os valores:

```
Número: {{Form::text('tel[]')}}
Proprietário: {{Form::select('proprietario[]',['Aluno'=>'Aluno','Pai'=>'Pai'])}}
Tipo: {{Form::select('tipo[]'['Pessoal'=>'Pessoal', 'Comercial'=>'Comercial'])}}
```

Estou tentando inserir no banco da seguinte forma:

```
    $telefone=$_POST['tel'];    
    $proprietario=$_POST['proprietario'];
    $tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
    if(count($telefone)>0){
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($telefone); $i++) {
            $tel->numero=$telefone[$i];
            $tel->proprietario=$proprietario[$i];
            $tel->tipo=$tipo[$i];
        }
    }
```

O problema é que só está inserindo o último valor do array. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Veja se no html gerado o `name` esta com colchetes.

Comment: Sim, está com colchetes.

Comment: você viu isso pelo `ctrl+u` do navegador?

Comment: Sim. Exibi o código-fonte da página

Comment: você já fez `dd($telefone)` para ver o que esta armazenado?

Comment: Já, está armazenando os dados corretamente na variável. A impressão que tenho, é que o `for` não percorre o array, porém dei um `echo` no `$i` e está ok.

Comment: Qual é o array da sua coleção inteira, consegue fazer um `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST); die();` ?

Comment: SIm, consigo. Os dados estão sendo captados pelo `$_POST` corretamente.

Comment: tenta colocar um `$tel->save()` no final do `foreach`

Comment: Já tem @RafaelAcioly

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, inverti e ainda assim continua inserindo apenas o último registro :(

Comment: @AmandaLima procura ajuda na comunidade laravel no `slack` lá com certeza eles podem te ajudar! https://laravel-br.slack.com/

Comment: Tá meio esquisito! `$_POST` no Laravel?!?!? não seria `Input::get`?

Comment: `$tel->tipo=$tipo[$i];` o sinal de igual para uma variável normal dentro de um loop, armazena apenas uma valor, sendo que estão a ser substituídos até chegar o último, por essa razão ficas apenas com as referências do último índice da array percorrida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depende do seu banco de dados.

Arrays representam mais de um dado.

Então eu creio que a forma correta seria, tomando por exemplo usuários e seus diversos telefones.

```
$dadosUsuario = Input::only('nome', 'email', 'idade');

$usuario = Usuario::create($dadosUsuario);

foreach((array) Input::get('telefones') as $telefone) 
{
      $dadosTelefone[] = [
            'usuario_id' => $usuario->id, 
            'telefone'   => $telefone

      ];
}
```

Se você for "inserir um `array` no banco" vai ter que fazer gambiarras como `json_encode`:

```
 $dadosUsuario = Input::only('nome', 'email', 'idade', 'telefones');

 $dadosUsuario['telefones'] = json_encode($telefones);

 Usuario::create($dadosUsuario);
```

Esse último exemplo é **altamente não-recomendável** rsrsrs

## No seu caso

Percebo que seu padrão de codificação no Laravel está um pouco diferente do que estou costumado a ver.

Mas acredito que essa informação é válida em todos os casos.

Só está inserindo o último valor, porque pra você inserir no banco, você tem que chamar o método `save` a cada iteração.

```
$telefone = $_POST['tel'];    

$proprietario = $_POST['proprietario'];

$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];

// Chamar o count a cada iteração é ruim

$count = count($telefone); 

if ($count > 0) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $tel->numero = $telefone[$i];
        $tel->proprietario = $proprietario[$i];
        $tel->tipo = $tipo[$i];

        $tel->save(); // Salva o paranauê
    }
}
```

Comment: Era justamente a falta do `save()` dentro do Loop, muito obrigada!

Comment: Amanda, sei que não responde sua pergunta. Apenas para recomendação, você não precisa usar $_POST dentro do laravel, você pode usar Input::get e para arquivo Input::file.